# Linq query returning same row 12 times

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Hi i have written one linq query to fetch records from entity model. I am getting perfect number of records but all are same.
here is my query

```
Entities.TEST.Where(a => a.ID.ToUpper().Equals(ID.ToUpper())).OrderBy(s => s.NAME).ToList();
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you investigate the SQL that is emitted to the database? And does the SQL on itself produce the right results?

Comment: I hope there is no problem in your for loop implementation when you iterate through the results? Please check it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make sure your Entity Key in your Entity Data Model is unique.

So in your example, ID should be the entity key for your Test entity

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have forgotten to apply Entity Key to entity..Thank you so much...:)

Comment: This can occur when using views in your data model - at least in my case that was the reason as there was no key in my view.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should work, i have a similar sample that works for northwind DB:

```
        var ctx = new NorthwindEntities();
        var emp = ctx.Employees.Where(e => e.TitleOfCourtesy.Equals("ms.", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).OrderBy(n => n.FirstName).ToList();
```

Please check your query in [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/). You will see the results and the generated SQL.

Comment: If a query does not work, telling that it should work is not really a solution, is it? You do provide better syntax, though.

Comment: It is a hint that the query maybe works, the user can play around with this similar sample. Maybe other problem is out there, that we can't see from the posted question.

Comment: @xeondev: Getting this error. `Cannot specify query options (orderby, where, take, skip) on single resource.`

Answer (score -2):

Replace Equals with == and you can go

Comment: Maybe, you have 12 elements with the same id?

Comment: No I dont have same record 12 times.

Comment: Such one-liner answers are not very valuable. At least provide some explanation as to why this should make a difference.